# One model with 2 categories in Django. How do I display another category from the same model in html?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I've created a class Product in **`models.py`** where I have 2 categories. I successfully displayed in my html page the category **connectors** but not the **software** which I left commented to see the data properly in html. How can I display the **software** category in html properly as I did with connectors? Thanks in advance for any tips!

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longDesc = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    version = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    picture = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True, related_name="products_image")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
```

The **`views.py`** contains the following code:

```
def products(request):
    objconnectors = Products.objects.all().filter(category__iexact='connectors')
    contextconn = {'connectors': objconnectors}
    # objsoftware = Products.objects.filter(category__iexact='software')
    # contextsoft = {'software': objsoftware}
    return render(request, 'website/products.html', contextconn, contextsoft)
```

The `html` file contains a loop to display all the data from the Products model, category Connectors.

```
{% for products in connectors %}
                            <div class="products animated delay1" data-effect="fadeInUp">
                                <div class="connectorWrap">
                                    <div class="productsTitle">
                                        <img src="{{ products.picture.url }}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="textBox">
                                        <h3>{{ products.title }}</h3>
                                        <p class="connDesc">{{ products.short_description }}</p>
                                        <p class="versionNumber">{{ products.version }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply using `context` dict.

**views.py**

```
def products(request):
    objconnectors = Products.objects.all().filter(category__iexact='connectors')
    objsoftware = Products.objects.filter(category__iexact='software')
    context = {
        'connectors': objconnectors,
        'softwares': objsoftware
    }
    return render(request, 'website/products.html', context)
```

**HTML File**

```
{% for products in connectors %}
 ... do here...
{% endfor %}
```

Similarly for other category

```
{% for products in softwares %}
 ... do here...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your tip! It works as expected.

Comment: @JustMe, glad that it helped. You can vote up and mark the answer as selected. Thanks.